# Excel subtracting dates does not work, see description below

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two dates for eg. 12/02/2001 and 22/04/2001. I want to get the difference between the two in days. But when I try = A2-A1 is gives me #VALUE!
On the other hand, =A1+1 works by adding 1 day.
However, I want the difference of the two dates. How do I fix this?

Comment: are you sure that excel is set to UK dates? 22/04/2001 is not a valid date in the US, and excel seems to like US dates for almost everything

Comment: I agree with Sean, if A1+1 works then presumably A1 is a valid date but A2 isn't - check by using ISNUMBER(A2) - if A2 is a date you get TRUE, I expect you'll get FALSE, where do the dates come from?

Comment: wrong! Excel will use the current locale settings, not US. Opening an Excel file created in German or French with `;` as function separator and `,` as decimal point in a UK or US locale will get you into trouble

Comment: Related: [How to prevent Excel to use the OS regional settings for date patterns in formulas](http://superuser.com/q/730371/348859)

Comment: The format for the dates should be "Date". Dates entered in cells should be based on the selected format type (MM-DD-YY)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `A1` is being interpreted properly as a date but `A2` is not. Make sure your locale is set to interpret dates in the European style dd/mm/yy instead of the US mm/dd/yy.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> =DATEDIF(Date1, Date2, Interval)

Where:
Date1 is the first date,
Date2 is the second date,
Interval is the interval type to return.

If Date1 is later than Date2, DATEDIF will return a #NUM! error. If either Date1 or Date2 is not a valid date, DATEDIF will return a #VALUE error.

For example

- Date1: 1-Jan-2007
- Date2: 10-Jan-2007
- Interval: d
- Result: 9

[Source](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datedif.aspx)

Or, use DATEVALUE()

> =DATEVALUE("9/29/2012")-DATEVALUE("9/10/2012")

[Source](http://legalofficeguru.com/calculate-dates-microsoft-excel/)

Comment: There are bugs in `DATEDIF` since Excel 2007 SP2 (I am not sure if it is fixed yet) esp when the `interval` parameter is "md". The function is not properly documented anyway; so if you are working on important data you may want to avoid using `DATEDIF`.  Ref http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/how-to-change-number-of-days-to-yearsmonths-and/d711c71e-8b71-4311-b568-57b6b4eee504

Answer (score 0):

Also check that the data type for your equation is general or numeric.  Had similar issues today and changing to "general" fixed everything.