# Excel Chart - show data formatted regardless the local settings

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, formatting, localization, regional-settings

I want to share a excel file with charts on a different computer. 
The data I have formatted to display with thousand (,) and decimal (.) separation char. 
Unfortunately the other computer is set up with thousand (') and decimal (.) separation chars. 
So the data isn't shown formatted as I have set it.

Both computers are running with windows.  
Mine has set the regional format to "German (Germany)". 
The second computer has it set to "German (Switzerland)".
How can I fix or lock the format of the chart?  
I have tried both formatting the data labels as well as the cell format, but it doesn't work. 
Is there a way to solve this without changing the regional format?

So that when I open the file on the other computer I can see the data as I see it on mine. 
I'm facing the same issues also with charts inside Word documents

Thank you for your help

**I have found the following related post** 
[Super User Post - format issue](https://superuser.com/questions/730371/how-to-prevent-excel-to-use-the-os-regional-settings-for-date-patterns-in-formul) 
It seems that the user has a similar issue.

Comment: Did you format the data labels or are you just using the default format Excel provides you?

Comment: I tried both. Formatting the data labels as the cell format doesn't work.