# Excel date format changes with different regional settings (2020-08-01 to 2020.08.01)

Tags: format, date, regional-settings, microsoft-excel-365

I searched most of the posts, but there is no solution to my problem.

This is what I tried using Excel 365 with English Windows Machine:

[image: Created with Excel 365 with English Windows Machine]

And this is what I get when I open the file with Excel 365 on a German Windows Machine:

[image: Opened with Excel 365 with German Windows Machine]

I thought removing the `*` from a formatting forces that format, no matter which region you open it in?

As you can see I tried other things too, but none works.

Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Excel to use the OS regional settings for date patterns in formulas](https://superuser.com/questions/730371/how-to-prevent-excel-to-use-the-os-regional-settings-for-date-patterns-in-formul)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Custom` formatting to format the date however you like.

1. Select the data you want to format
2. Go to `Home` ➡ `Number` ➡ `More Number Formats...`:
   [image]
3. Go to the `Custom` category and type in the desired format in the `Type:` field:
   [image]

If I for example type `dd-mm-yyyy` I get to see `01-08-2020`. Other examples are shown below:

[image]

<sub>I believe the custom format survives locale formatting, but I don't have a machine with a different locale to test and am to lazy to switch on this machine.</sub>

Comment: That is excatly what I tried and it looks like custom format eg "yyyy-mm-dd" does not survive a different locale. So frustrating! :-)

Comment: @schluk5 ok, it was entirely not clear from your question that you've tried this already. What happens with the dummy `dd$mm€yyyy` custom format? Does it also simply override that?

Comment: This one actually is not changed. So it must have something to do with '-' beeing transformed to '.' for whatever reason. Do you know of a way to force the '-' with the custom formatting?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found now is to format that specific cells as text and then reenter the dates eg 2020-08-01. This works so far, but you need to work with `=TEXT(,)` formula with the right formatting eg `=TEXT(, "yyyy-mm-dd")`, when you want to refer to that cell.