# why add a dollar sign to a vba function

Tags: vba

In another question I see a dollar sign at the end of a excel vba function. I cannot find anywhere what is the impact of this syntax.

[How to prevent Excel to use the OS regional settings for date patterns in formulas](https://superuser.com/questions/730371/how-to-prevent-excel-to-use-the-os-regional-settings-for-date-patterns-in-formul/917519#917519)

```
Public Function GetFormat$(Cell As Range, Optional ByVal UseLocal As Boolean)
    If UseLocal Then
        GetFormat = Cell.NumberFormatLocal
    Else
        GetFormat = Cell.NumberFormat
    End If
End Function
```

I checked, it works, but why ?

Comment: As I understand it, it forces the return as a string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389444/what-does-the-symbol-do-in-vba

Comment: thats it, thanks for the link and the answer.